# Can my charger power Raspberry pi 4?

Tags: power-supply

I am new to Raspberry pi and I wonder do I need to buy a charger because in my country they cost a lot and when I examine my charger I saw that 5V 3A and I thought Raspberry pi 4 charger is 5V 3A too. And as far as I remember everyone said to me I need to power up my Raspberry with a good charger or my Raspberry will burn or something like that. So can my charger power Raspberry pi 4?[image]

Comment: You say: "and I thought Raspberry pi 4 charger is 5V 3A too." - does this mean your R Pi is battery powered, else why would you use a (pulsating DC) charger instead of a regulated DC power supply?

Comment: My native language is not English so I made some mistakes when I wrote the question that's why I wrote charger instead of adapter because I forgot and I thought both of them have same meanings so it says 5V 3A 15W and I think Raspberry pi need 5.1V 3A 10W but can my adapter power Raspberry pi 4? I am asking this question because I am 15 years old, I am going to buy Raspberry with my own money and I dont want to waste money for the things I dont need to. My parents already dont want me to buy Raspberry because it costs a lot and I am trying to be sure about it.

Comment: and you can just say "oh this person just made a mistake about choosing words I will read "charger" as "adapter"(or what else does that thing called) and answer his question." but you all are professionals right? I already said I am new so you can say I am not talking about some complicated things. I just wanted to learn if my adapter can power raspberry pi 4. And I uploaded a photo too so you can what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the device supplies 5V at an amp or so your Pi will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is a multi voltage charger: 5V or 9V or 12V depending on what it is plugged into. If the charger gets it wrong for whatever reason when your Pi4 is plugged in, your Pi is dead.

I certainly would not risk plugging that into any Pi.

Buy the official power supply, even if more expensive:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/type-c-power-supply/